# Spark Best Practise: Persist modifictions on objects

Tags: java, apache-spark

### Setting

There is a Spark RDD with some complex objects. I would like to run a method on each of the objects that modifies the internal state of that object. Afterwards I would like to persist an RDD of the modified objects.

### Example

Lets have an RDD of objects which contain text blocks. The goal is to apply some preprocessing on each of the text blocks in order to to build an index structure. The index structure is saved inside the object alongside the textblock. Lets say that objects inherit the following interface:

```
public interface IndexedTextBlock {
    public void preprocess();
    public boolean eval(string query);
}
```

I have no access to the internals of that object and thus cannot externalize that index into a tuple alongside the text block. Later I would like to reuse that object for multiple queries on the text blocks. So I would like to do something like this:

```
JavaRDD<IndexedTextBlock> textBlocks = .....;
processedTextBlocks = textBlocks.foreach(tb -> tb.preprocess()).persist();
processedTextBlocks.map(tb -> tb.eval("query1"));
processedTextBlocks.map(tb -> tb.eval("query2"));
...
```

### Question

All real solutions that come into my mind are some kind of hackish. E.g.:

```
processedTextBlocks = textBlocks.map(tb -> {tb.preprocess(); return tb;}).persist()
```

I guess there are better ways to do it. Please enlight me!

Comment: At lines 3 and 4 you are applying eval on objects from a non persisted RDD. Was that intended ?

Comment: "I would like to run a method on each of the objects that modifies the internal state of that object.": not a wonderful idea, because Spark is all about sharing & immutability

Comment: @baitmbarek: you are right, thx